# How to do LEFT OUTER JOIN on Django ORM on non ForeignKey field

Tags: django, django-orm

I have 2 models:

```
model A:
  name = CharField()
  ...

model B:
  title = CharField(null=True)
  ...
```

I want to get all record of model **A** which do not have record in model **B** by "name" = "title"

ON SQL I got this by:

```
SELECT  "A".* 
    FROM "A"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "B"
     ON "A"."name" = "B"."title"
WHERE "B"."title" IS NULL
```

How to write this using Django ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `exclude` with a subquery of all titles from model `B` as following:

`A.objects.exclude(name__in=B.objects.all().values('title))`

Comment: Looks not exactly the same as SQL that I gives but it works and give me that I want, really simple solution, thx! I guess I need a little rest :)